# Local transparent proxy OS X pf

Tags: proxy, pf, osx-lion

I was trying to create local transparent proxy using this pf rules:

```
rdr pass inet proto tcp from $Out to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 3129
pass out on $Out route-to lo0  inet proto tcp from $Out to any port 80 keep state
```

but the problem is that when proxy server is trying to connect to remote server(port 80) it also gets redirected creating infinite redirection loop. Is there anything i can do?

Answer (score 0):

Yup. Second line (first non-nat rule) isn't needed at all.

Use something like `set skip on lo0` - you don't need to filter it anyway.

Comment: At the beginning I thought so too, but when i remove the second line there is no redirection at all

Comment: You are probably redirecting on wrong interface. The rdr rule must match packets from internal network to the outer world, and its better to use it with the interface.

Comment: i'm redirecting from only active interface which is en0 on my mac.

Comment: What do you need to redirect packets from your own machine for ?

Comment: I want to use squid interception proxy.

Comment: Use `user` filter statement to let the proxy out of the loop. But the whole concept still seems  weird.

Comment: i don't know that statement, how can i use it?

Comment: it depends on the user your proxy is running under. like, for example, `pass out on $oiface inet proto tcp from $oip to any port 80 user squid` - try this as third rule.